# Create Hierarchies table or query from multi parent table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data

Please help me to convert my table(like sample) to hierarchical structure in SQL. actually i want to make a table from my data in SQL for a TreeList control datasource in VB.net application directly.

ProjectID is 1st Parent 
Type_1 is 2nd Parent
Type_2 is 3rd Parent
Type_3 is 4ed Parent

Thanks

My Samlpe Data:

```
declare @table table (idsupply int,projectid varchar(20),SubProject varchar(20),Type_1 varchar(20),Type_2 varchar(20),Type_3 varchar(20),AssemblyName varchar(20))

insert into @table
values  (1,'A06','A06','Column','LateralColumn',null,'KPC8'),
        (2,'A06','A06','Column','LateralColumn',null,'KPC7'),
        (3,'A06','A06','Column','LateralColumn',null,'KPC5'),
        (4,'A06','A06','Gutter','MiddleGutter',null,'KPC1'),
        (5,'A06','A06','PurLine',null,null,'KPPU10'),
        (6,'A06','A06','Column','LateralColumn',null,'KPC3'),
        (7,'A06','A06','Column','MiddleColumn',null,'KAC9'),
        (8,'A06','A06','Flange Stay',null,null,'KPFS3'),
        (9,'A06','A06','PurLine',null,null,'KPPU11'),
        (10,'A06','A06','Column','LateralColumn','Double','KPC18'),
        (11,'A06','A06','Column','LateralColumn','Double','KPC19'),
        (12,'A06','A06','Column','LateralColumn','Mono','KPC20'),
        (13,'A06','A06','Column','LateralColumn','Mono','KPC21')

        select * from @table
```

Comment: post your reqired table structure

Comment: ----------------------------
| ID | ParentID | Name |
----------------------------

Comment: I think you're going to need to describe your data a bit more for anyone to help you intelligently. One can infer a project table, a supplier table, and perhaps an assembly table, but beyond that it's hard to know more detail about what you need.

Comment: I want to make datasource for my Treelist control directly from SQL. I can do that programmatically in vb.net.
My hierarchical data has 6 level (fixed) and last level is AssemblyName.

Comment: Given your sample data, what would your resulting data look like?   What would the ParentID be for each of the rows in your sample data?   And why?

Comment: ok.give samle output too

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table (idsupply int,projectid varchar(20),SubProject varchar(20),Type_1 varchar(20),Type_2 varchar(20),Type_3 varchar(20),AssemblyName varchar(20))
declare @ProjectIDCount bigint
declare @SubProjectCount  bigint
declare @Type_1Count bigint
declare @Type_2Count bigint 
declare @Type_3Count  bigint 


insert into @table
values  (1,'A06','SA06','Column','LateralColumn',null,'KPC8'),
        (2,'A06','SA06','Column','LateralColumn',null,'KPC7'),
        (3,'A06','SA06','Column','LateralColumn',null,'KPC5'),
        (4,'A06','SA06','Gutter','MiddleGutter',null,'KPGU1'),
        (5,'A06','SA06','PurLine',null,null,'KPPU10'),
        (6,'A06','SA06','Column','LateralColumn',null,'KPC3'),
        (7,'A06','SA06','Column','MiddleColumn',null,'KAC9'),
        (8,'A06','SA06','Flange Stay',null,null,'KPFS3'),
        (9,'A06','SA06','PurLine',null,null,'KPPU11'),
        (10,'A06','SA06','Column','LateralColumn','Double','KPC18'),
        (11,'A06','SA06','Column','LateralColumn','Double','KPC19'),
        (12,'A06','SA06','Column','LateralColumn','Mono','KPC20'),
        (13,'A06','SA06','Column','LateralColumn','Mono','KPC21'),
        (14,'A06','SA06','Column','LateralColumn',null,'KPC22')


Set @ProjectIDCount =(SELECT COUNT(ProjectID) AS ProjectIDCount FROM (SELECT ProjectID FROM @table GROUP BY ProjectID) AS tab1001 )
set @SubProjectCount=(SELECT COUNT(SubProject) AS ProjectIDCount FROM (SELECT SubProject FROM @table GROUP BY SubProject) AS tab1002 )+@ProjectIDCount
set @Type_1Count=(SELECT COUNT(Type_1) AS ProjectIDCount FROM (SELECT Type_1 FROM @table GROUP BY Type_1) AS tab1003 )+@SubProjectCount
set @Type_2Count=(SELECT COUNT(Type_2) AS ProjectIDCount FROM (SELECT Type_2 FROM @table GROUP BY Type_2) AS tab1004 )+@Type_1Count
set @Type_3Count=(SELECT COUNT(Type_3) AS ProjectIDCount FROM (SELECT Type_3 FROM @table GROUP BY Type_3) AS tab1005 )+@Type_2Count

;WITH cte as (
   SELECT *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY projectid)  as ID_parent,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY projectid,SubProject)  as ID_SubProject,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY projectid,SubProject,Type_1)  as ID_Type1,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY projectid,SubProject,Type_1,Type_2)  as ID_Type2,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY projectid,SubProject,Type_1,Type_2,Type_3)  as ID_Type3,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY projectid,SubProject,Type_1,Type_2,Type_3,AssemblyName)  as ID_AssemblyName
   FROM @table 
), hier as (
   SELECT DISTINCT ID_Parent as ID, null as Parent, projectid as IDName FROM cte
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT @ProjectIDCount+ID_SubProject as ID, ID_Parent as Parent, SubProject as IDName FROM cte
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT @SubProjectCount+ID_Type1 as ID, @ProjectIDCount+ID_SubProject as Parent, Type_1 as IDName FROM cte
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT @Type_1Count+ID_Type2 as ID, @SubProjectCount+ID_Type1 as Parent, Type_2 as IDName FROM cte
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT @Type_2Count+ID_Type3 as ID, @Type_1Count+ID_Type2 as Parent, Type_3 as IDName FROM cte
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT @Type_3Count+ID_AssemblyName as ID, @Type_2Count+ID_Type3 as Parent, AssemblyName as IDName FROM cte
)

select * FROM hier where (IDName is not null)
```